# BOOST block_prod matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, boost, matrix

code is

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/operation.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

int main () {

    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m (1000, 1000);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> n (1000, 1000);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> mn (1000, 1000);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1 (); ++ i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2 (); ++ j)
            m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n.size1 (); ++ i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n.size2 (); ++ j)
            n (i, j) = 2 * i + j;

    mn = block_prod<matrix<double>, 1024>(m, n);

    return 0;
}
```

but i get these errors:

```
newfile.cpp:88: error: ‘block_prod’ is not a member of ‘boost::numeric::ublas’
newfile.cpp:88: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
newfile.cpp:88: error: no match for ‘operator>’ in ‘1024 > (0, n)’
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't locate these errors. I appreciate any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your includes

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/operation_blocked.hpp>
```